# Using cucumber with staging database without truncation and transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

We have a Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 project, where data are almost exclusively read only. 
We would like to write acceptance tests which use staging database (copy of the production database)

So we do not want to use transactions or truncation of the database tables before or after features and scenarios.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you confusing cucumber and rspec?

Comment: I use rspec and capybara for integration tests, and they work just fine as they are. For acceptance tests I would like to use cucumber, and because of complexity of real data I want to use staging database

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch DatabaseCleaner to transaction cleaning strategy in features/support/env.rb

```
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  begin
    require 'database_cleaner'
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  rescue LoadError => ignore_if_database_cleaner_not_present
  end
end
```

And monkey patch DatabaseCleaner by adding features/support/database_cleaner_patch.rb with

```
module DatabaseCleaner::ActiveRecord
  #for now we will disable transactions 
  class Transaction

    def start
    end

    def clean
    end
  end
end
```

We have 3 databases in our project, with cross-database queries so we cannot use transactions, otherwise I would not monkey patch DatabaseCleaner